# How to pass public functions from class as a parameter in another function.

Tags: c++, function, oop, pointers, parameters

Im trying to pass the "get" functions within my class, as a parameter into a "display" function outside of my class. 
I have looked all over the web for ways to do this and there doesn't seem to be a clearly stated anywhere.
AAMOI- Can you do this without pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class student{
public:
    void setVAr(int x, int y, int z){
        phone=x;
        house=y;
        rollno=z;
    };
    int getPhone(){
         return phone;
    };
    int getHouse(){
        return house;
    };
    int getRollno(){
        return rollno;
    };
private:
    int phone;
    int house;
    int rollno;
};
void display(student anyStu, int * funcA, int * funcB, int * funcC);
int main(){
    int x=0,y=0,z=0;
    student jack;
    cout<<"Please enter in your phone no:"<<endl;
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"Please enter in your house no.: "<<endl;
    cin>>y;
    cout<<"Enter your rollno: "<<endl;
    cin>>z;
    jack.setVAr(x,y,z);

    cout<<"Your Phone no is: "<<jack.getPhone()<<endl;
    cout<<"Your house no: "<<jack.getHouse()<<endl;
    cout<<"Your rollno no: "<<jack.getRollno()<<endl;
    display(jack,&jack.getPhone(),&jack.getHouse(),&jack.getRollno());
};
void display(student anyStu,int * funcA, int * funcB, int * funcC){
    cout<<"Your Phone no is: "<<anyStu.getPhone()<<endl;
    cout<<"Your house no: "<<anyStu.getHouse()<<endl;
    cout<<"Your rollno no: "<<anyStu.getRollno()<<endl;
};
```

Comment: funcA/B/C are parameters to hold the arguments of get.Phone/.House/.Rollno. Very simple functions, but hard to pass function into a function, very few tutorials on this.

Answer (score 2):

First, pass `anyStu` by reference, like `void display( const student &anyStu, ... )` so you're not copying the object (and making it `const` for good measure to indicate you're not modifying it). Also make the get functions const like this `int getHouse() const {`; second, if you have the reference already, why not just use the get functions (e.g. `anyStu.getPhone()`) instead of trying to pass them (which you can't do since they're part of an instance)?  An interface class might be in order if that doesn't fit...

```
void display(const student &anyStu){
    cout<<"Your Phone no is: "<<anyStu.getPhone()<<endl;
    cout<<"Your house no: "<<anyStu.getHouse()<<endl;
    cout<<"Your rollno no: "<<anyStu.getRollno()<<endl;
};
```

and call like:

```
display(jack);
```

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question.

Comment: you're right it doesn't, but it felt more like an education/steering-type of answer was in order...

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear from your code example *why* you want it but I think what you are looking for is a *pointer-to-member function*. For example this creates a pointer to the member function `getPhone` called `funcA`:

```
int(student::*funcA)() = &student::getPhone;
```

Or in C++11 just:

```
auto funcA = &student::getPhone;
```

And then you can invoke it by doing:

```
(jack.*funcA)()
```

I prefer to use `typedef`s or C++11 `using` aliases for pointer-to-member functions because the syntax can be a bit confusing. Then your example, incorporating some of the suggestions by Mark, would look something like:

```
#include <iostream>

class student {
public:
    void setVAr(int x, int y, int z){
        phone=x;
        house=y;
        rollno=z;
    }
    int getPhone() const { return phone; }
    int getHouse() const { return house; }
    int getRollno() const { return rollno; }
private:
    int phone;
    int house;
    int rollno;
};

using Func = int (student::*)() const;  // C++11
//typedef int(student::Func*)() const;  // C++98

void display(const student& anyStu, Func funcA, Func funcB, Func funcC){
    std::cout<<"A: "<<(anyStu.*funcA)()<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"B: "<<(anyStu.*funcB)()<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"C: "<<(anyStu.*funcC)()<<"\n";
}

int main(){
    student jack;
    jack.setVAr(911,42,1);

    display(jack, &student::getPhone, &student::getHouse, &student::getRollno);
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0XulLalX2AMKcFtw).

You could also consider using C++11 [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of pointer-to-member function. Your function type could be a function that takes a `student` as a parameter and returns an int. You can then use a lambda to wrap the member functions:

```
#include <functional>

using Func = std::function<int(const student&)>;

void display(const student& anyStu, Func funcA, Func funcB, Func funcC){
    std::cout<<"A: "<<funcA(anyStu)<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"B: "<<funcB(anyStu)<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"C: "<<funcC(anyStu)<<"\n";
}

int main(){
    student jack;
    jack.setVAr(911,42,1);

    auto getPhone = [](const student& s){ return s.getPhone(); };
    auto getHouse = [](const student& s){ return s.getHouse(); };
    auto getRollno = [](const student& s){ return s.getRollno(); };

    display(jack, getPhone, getHouse, getRollno);
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ReImWlLgN95imlC1).